# How to use the stored value of combo box to SQL connection String?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have stored the output of a combobox to a variable:

```
var MyVariable = combobox.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

And my question is how to use this variable to an SQL connection string?

```
string connectionString;
SqlConnection cnn;
connectionString = @"Data Source=DAYRMOTSTSQL05\SE;Initial Catalog=?;Integrated Security=True;";
cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
cnn.Open();
cnn.Close();
```

I need the variable value in Initial Catalog, Please help me out for this.

Comment: You say "in VB.NET" but your code is in C#. They're two different languages. Which one are you actually using? Anyway, look into [`String.Format()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format) and [String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Answer (score 1):

```
using (var cnn = new SqlConnection($"Data Source=DAYRMOTSTSQL05\\SE;Initial Catalog={combobox.SelectedItem};Integrated Security=True;"))
{
    cnn.Open();

} //using block will close the connection automatically, even if an exception is thrown
//The original code would have left the connection open if you had an exception
```

Comment: Can I use String concatenate here?